# Does the surya namaskara mantra declare surya as Brahman?

Tags: surya

I can't find any text of this vedic mantra.where does it declare surya as supreme brahman?

Comment: Can you quote the mantra in question?

Comment: Unless you provide the sloka in question, the question is leaving so many options to the reader.  And, it is liable to be closed.